# scale_pos_weight using XGBoost's Learning API

Tags: machine-learning, python, xgboost

I see it is possible to add a weight for unbalanced problems in XGBoost's [Scikit-Learn API](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn) through **scale_pos_weight**. Does it have an equivalent in the [Learning API](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.training)? If not,

- is there a reason behind this?
- Could this corrective factor/weight also be somehow implemented using the learning API?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `scale_pos_weight` in the native python API; it goes in the `params` dictionary.  E.g.,

```
params = {'objective': 'binary:logistic',
          'scale_pos_weight': 2.5}
model = xgboost.train(params, dmat)
```

https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html#parameters-for-tree-booster
https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/demo/kaggle-higgs/speedtest.py